# Double rules in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have these .htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to region page (xxxxx.com/project-list.php?lang=fr&region=1)
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/(.+)$  project-list.php?lang=$1&region=$2 [L]

# Redirect to project page (xxxxx.com/projet-details.php?lang=fr&region=1&projet=1)
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/(.+)/(.+)$  project-details.php?lang=$1&region=$2&projet=$3 [L]
```

The first one, works like a charm.

But not the second one. If I want it work for the second one, I need to remove the first one.

How can I change that behaviour please ?

Comment: Both rules have a same uri pattern, Rule processing starts from the top ,so definitely the first one matches..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reorder your rules like this :

```
RewriteEngine On


# Redirect to project page (xxxxx.com/projet-details.php?lang=fr&region=1&projet=1)
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/(.+)/(.+)$  project-details.php?lang=$1&region=$2&projet=$3 [L]

# Redirect to region page (xxxxx.com/project-list.php?lang=fr&region=1)
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/(.+)$  project-list.php?lang=$1&region=$2 [L]
```